# Menu icons position are different

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I use in menu icon search for show in wordpress search toogle bar. Wordpress theme use simple js custom file. This is all about website and menu. But for newsletter i have take plugin newsletter subscription.

If you see menu icons position [visit website here](http://wpcard.net/)

My problem is : I want to block in menu bar icon search and newsletter icon the same position. Now if you click search icon you will see change newsletter position.

This is my js file :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) { 

    //Javascript Detection
    $('body').removeClass('no-js');     
    //Read More Link
    function readmorelink() {
        $('a.more-link').closest('p').css('text-align', 'center');
    }
    readmorelink();

    //Flexslider
    function flexslider() {
        $('.flexslider').flexslider({
            animation: "fade",
            slideshow: false,
        });

        $(".flex-next").html('<i class="icon-chevron-right"></i>');
        $(".flex-prev").html('<i class="icon-chevron-left"></i>');
    }
    flexslider();
        //Fitvid
    function fitvids() {
        $(".featured-preview").fitVids();   
    }
    fitvids();  

    //Comments Toggle
    $(".comments-wrapper").hide();
    $("#comments-title").attr('class', 'comments-close');

    $("#comments-title").toggle(function () {
        $(".comments-wrapper").slideDown();
        $(this).attr('class', 'comments-open');
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#comments-title").offset().top
        }, 0);
        return false;
    }, function (){
        $(".comments-wrapper").slideUp();
        $(this).attr('class', 'comments-close');
        return false;
    })  

    //Infinite Scroll
    if ((custom_js_vars.infinite_scroll) == 'no') { 

    } else { 
        $('.posts').infinitescroll({
              loading: {
                  msgText: "...Loading Posts...",
                  finishedMsg: "- End of Posts -"
              },
              nextSelector: '.post-nav-next a',
              navSelector: '.post-nav',
              itemSelector: 'article',
              contentSelector: '.posts',
              appendCallback: true
        },function () { 
            fitvids();
            readmorelink();
            flexslider();
        });     
    }



    $( ".icon-medium.icon-search" ).click(function() {
      $(".nksub-tab-icon").toggleClass("newClass");
    });

    $( ".icon-medium.icon-search" ).click(function() {
        $(".nksub-tab-icon").delay(1000).queue(function(next){
            $(this).toggleClass("newClass");
            next();
        });
    });

    //Cabinet Toggle
    $('#cabinet-toggle, #cabinet-toggle-mobile').click(function () {            
        $("#cabinet-slider").slideToggle(0);
        $(".icon-plus-sign").attr('class', 'icon-minus-sign');
        return false;
    }, function () {
        $("#cabinet-slider").slideToggle(0);

        $(".icon-minus-sign").attr('class', 'icon-plus-sign');
        return false;
    });     
    //Responsive Menu
    $('.nav').mobileMenu();

    $('select.select-menu').each(function(){
        var title = $(this).attr('title');
        if( $('option:selected', this).val() != ''  ) title = $('option:selected',this).text();
        $(this)
            .css({'z-index':10,'-khtml-appearance':'none'})
            .after('<span class="select"></span>')
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS, you have this:

```
body:not([class*=nksub_mobile]) .nks_cc_trigger_tabs.nksub_tab {
    top: 327px !important;
   }
```

This will make the icon appear 327 pixels from the top of the screen always. So, when you click on the search icon, the search field appears on top and the 327px is not enough to keep the email newsletter icon on the same level with the search icon.

Workaround: in your:

```
$( ".icon-medium.icon-search" ).click(function() {
  $(".nksub-tab-icon").toggleClass("newClass");
  });
```

In the above function, add some CSS Class to your newsletter selector to adjust the position. Something around 327px + the height of the search box that appears on top.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I use `<style>
   
    .newClass {
  background-color:yellow;
margin-top:40px;
 }
  </style>`

Comment: This could work also.. Did it solve your problem? if so, please mark this as the answer :)